# symfony2 - standalone dic

Tags: php, symfony

I have tried to use symfony2 standalone dependency injection container in a custom MVC application.  But I am not sure how to access the services registered in the files across my application.  Since I am not using the entire symfony framework what is the best way to access the services in the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `Symfony` DIC here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html

It pretty much covers the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html ?

Your project can only depend on the DependencyInjection Component (https://github.com/symfony/DependencyInjection).

Result of a DI-setup is always the container itself. You can access it via `Container::get($id)`